# PowerShell 2.0 cannot handle space in $Env:PSModulePath?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

It appears that PowerShell 2.0 cannot handle a space in the Env:PSModulePath variable when looking for a module. I have the function in a .psm1 file in a directory under the "\ORGHOST\USRSHR\USERS\lit\My Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules" directory.

My organization requires that my Windows document directory be on a network share. This causes the $Env:PSModulePath variable to have "My Documents" as part of the path in the first entry. No, I cannot change the policies set by the organization.

It sounds like I should iterate over the paths in $Env:PSModulePath and find the short (8.3) name for each, then set $Env:PSModulePath using those in my profile script. I would welcome a better suggestion. Any ideas?

If anyone could confirm that this is a problem in PowerShell 2.0, that would be helpful in pushing the organization to upgrade to PowerShell 5.0.

```
PS 5.0
PS C:\src\powershell> $Env:PSModulePath -split ";"
\\ORGHOST\ORGSHR\Users\lit\My Documents\WindowsPowerShell
C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules
C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules

PS 2.0
PS C:\Users\lit> $Env:PSModulePath -split ";"
\\ORGHOST\ORGSHR\USERS\lit\My Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules
C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\PowerShell\Modules\

The term 'Phs-RunBat' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At \\ORGHOST\USRSHR\Users\lit\Scripts\PSAutomation\Phs-RunRemoteBat.ps1:17 char:23
+ [int32]$r = Phs-RunBat <<<< -ComputerName $ComputerName -ScriptPath $ScriptPath -LogFile $LogFile -Verbose
+ CategoryInfo : ObjectNotFound: (Phs-RunBat:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: `$paths = $Env:PSModulePath -split ";"`

Comment: @AustinFrench - I have edited the question to make use of your suggestion. That is a nice way to produce a list of the paths. Does this help explain the issue more clearly or are you suggesting that I change each path to a short (8.3) path and put it back into PSModulePath?

Comment: Do not put it back in PSModule path. Store it in a variable and dynamically use that path throughout the script. Thats one of the major reason PS got updated very quickly to version 3 from 2.

Comment: @RanadipDutta - Many thanks. I will ask the organization helpdesk about getting my profile path set to something that does not contain a space character. I will also encourage the organization to update PowerShell to 5.1. I am not holding my breath for either, but I would rather not embed this workaround in the code if possible. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/wmf/5.1/install-configure